# SQLite/Java: enable memory caching, redice I/O as much as possible

Tags: java, sqlite

I am using SQLite to persist non-critical information to disk. Database I am working with is relatively small, up to **10Gb**. At the same time workstation has plenty of RAM to keep it all in memory.

What I want is to reduce disk writes as much as possible, dumping whole database to disk once an hour would be brilliant solution.

Java <> SQLite connection is done via `org.xerial.sqlite-jdbc` JDBC driver.

Connection string is like:

```
"jdbc:sqlite:/disk/persistence.db"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not critical, just use an in-memory database, and never write it to disk at all.

If the data is more critical and you do want to save it, you can use [PRAGMA synchronous = OFF](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous) or even [PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) to avoid some writes, at the cost of possible data corruption.

If you want to avoid all writes, use an in-memory database, and manually make an on-disk copy with the backup API.